# "I took my shirt off" or "I took off my shirt"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, word-order

Which usage is correct/formal with clothes?

> I took my shirt off.

or

> I took off my shirt.

I've seen both of these usage. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatical. I don't really distinguish between the two forms, but *take off your shirt* might be slightly more casual.

Using Google Ngram Viewer, I confirmed my suspicion that *I took off my shirt* [is the more popular form](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20took%20off%20my%20shirt%2C%20I%20took%20my%20shirt%20off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20took%20off%20my%20shirt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20took%20my%20shirt%20off%3B%2Cc0). In general, I think *take off* is more common.

Comment: To *take off my shirt* means that at this moment, I am taking off my shirt. *Took off my shirt* means that I have already taken off my shirt. I think that they have different meanings and are not interchangeable as  this answer suggests.